How do I get this for loop to check each character every time?
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
print(chosen_word)

placeholder = ""
word_length = len(chosen_word)
for position in range(word_length):
    placeholder += "_"
print(placeholder)

# TODO-1: - Use a while loop to let the user guess again.

guess = ""
guess_list= []
display = ""
i = 0

# TODO-2: Change the for loop so that you keep the previous correct letters in display.

while display != chosen_word and i != word_length  :
     for letter in chosen_word:
         guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
         if guess in guess_list:
             print("You already guessed this letter")
         elif letter == guess and guess not in guess_list:
             display += letter
             i += 1
             guess_list += guess
         else:
             display += "_"
             i += 1



print(display)
print(guess_list)

I am trying to go through the 100 days of python programming and I'm trying to make the hangman game for day 7. I have it to where it will check the characters and even tell me if I've guessed a character but the problem is it will then skip to the next character in the sequence. So say the word is camel and I guess 'c' and then guess 'c' again to test to make sure it tells me I have already guessed that letter. It does! which is great, BUT then the for loop moves onto m in the sequence and doesn't retry checking for a. This ends up moving it to the else part of the statement then the whole loop restarts.

I don't understand what your program is supposed to do. Why are you looping over the letters in the word when asking for the guess? Do they have to guess the letters in order?

Why not just if guess in chosen_word: without looping over the letters?

You don't need and guess not in guess_list. That must be true since the previous if condition failed.

I agree with @Barmar you need only check if the current guess is in the previously guessed list. To further optimize the guess_list should be a dict like guess_dict so the lookups are O(1) vs looping through the entire list.     if guess in guess_dict

@QueensCoder If this is a hangman-type game, order is important. And some of the words have duplicate letters, like a in aardvark. So a dict or set is not appropriate.

What you're looking for is a break statement in your loop to stop the rest of the execution:
if guess in guess_list:
    print("You already guessed this letter")
    break

A Great resource which explains this in great detail can be found here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue
